# Is part of the declaration of 2 modules on ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic3

When I run the `ionic cordova build android --release --prod` command, the following error message is generated in the console

Can someone give me a way of how I should proceed? Because I'm waiting for this to publish my app

```
 `Type LoginPage in c:/Users/Mike/Desktop/GuiaCorretor/src/pages/login/login.ts is part of the declarations of
  2 modules: AppModule in c:/Users/Mike/Desktop/GuiaCorretor/src/app/app.module.ts and LoginPageModule`
```

This is my `app.module.ts`

```
import { LoginPage } from './../pages/login/login';
import { SobrePage } from '../pages/sobre/sobre';
import { PrediosPage } from "../pages/predios/predios";
import { NovidadesPage } from '../pages/novidades/novidades';
import { SocialPage } from '../pages/social/social';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage,
    SobrePage,
    PrediosPage,
    NovidadesPage,
    SocialPage,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(FIREBASE_CONFIG),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot()

  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    LoginPage,
    SobrePage,
    PrediosPage,
    NovidadesPage,
    SocialPage,

  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And this my `login.module.ts`
Did I mention the import? in my `login.module.ts`

```
`import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { LoginPage } from './login';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LoginPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(LoginPage),
  ],
})
export class LoginPageModule {}
`
```

[![As a complement I leave this image to show the following error that appears in my terminal
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuUN3.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuUN3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is remove the declaration of the LoginPage from your AppModule, and import the LoginModule in your AppModule instead. You can only declare your LoginPage in one module.

Comment: Could you please put an example? Because I did it and I could not

Comment: Thank you so much.